# why the django restframework's "request" not working?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have below DRF code that is instantiating a class that has GET method,

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework import status

class MrgCompInsert(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            # Use rest_framework.request.Request to make the initial request
            merge_company_info_view = MrgCompInfo.as_view()(Request(request))
            organization_data_response = merge_company_info_view.data

            if organization_data_response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
                # Access the data attribute from the Response object
                organization_data_post = organization_data_response.data

                post_url = 'https://example.com/
                # Use rest_framework.request.Request to make the subsequent request
                merge_to_kloo_post = Request(request).client.post(post_url, organization_data_post, format='json')

                if merge_to_kloo_post.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
                    return Response({'message': 'Data sent successfully to the second API'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                else:
                    return Response({'error': 'Failed to send data to the second API'},
                                    status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            else:
                return Response({'error': 'Failed to retrieve Category list'},
                                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

and then doing a POST on an another restful API. The GET APIView class individually is working fine. But the POST APIView class is causing issue, and I am getting below error.

```
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "error": "The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`."
}
```

Then imported request from django.http as shown below

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

organization_data_response = MrgCompInfo(HttpRequest)
merge_to_post = HttpRequest().POST(post_url, organization_data_post, format='json'),
```

still I am getting same error. Please suggest....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **requests** you are using is a wrapper of the rest framework itself, not a tool for http requests

Use the [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) library to achieve your goal

```
import requests
response = requests.post(url="https://example.com/", data="<some_data>")
```

Comment: Yes, I had this option, but why can't we do this through DRF code modules? any particular reason? would like to know for the learning purpose.

Comment: Of course, you can read the description in the documentation itself
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/